# Ffmpeg create video slideshow with images overlay others and zooming

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg command that can make image overlay others and zooming, but zooming effect is not working fine, it work only inside overlay image frame.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i pic001.jpg -i pic002.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:720,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125,trim=duration=5[scaled_video];[1:v]scale=1920:1080,boxblur=15[blur_image];[blur_image][scaled_video]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[outv]" -c:v libx264 -aspect 1280/720 -map [outv] -t 10 -y fixed.mp4
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Overlay filter does not support dynamic sizing, so you'll need a hack to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i pic001.jpg -i pic002.jpg -filter_complex
 "[0:v]scale=-1:720,format=yuva422p,pad=1.5*iw:1.5*ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=black@0,
  zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125:s=WxH,
  trim=duration=5[scaled_video];
  [1:v]scale=1920:1080,boxblur=15[blur_image];
  [blur_image][scaled_video]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[outv]"
-c:v libx264 -aspect 1280/720 -map [outv] -t 10 -y fixed.mp4
```

The trick is to add an alpha channel and then pad the image with transparent black. When overlaid, due to the alpha, the black padding disappears.

In the zoompan, you'll have to manually substitute W and H with the width & height of the padded image. In this case, it's 1.5 x width and 1.5 x height of the image after the initial scaling. I chose 1.5 as a multiplier since that's the maximum zoom level in zoompan.

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much.How can I make pad smaller. I want the image zoom in until it reach the top of background.

Comment: Increase the max zoom, and the pad multiplier as well.